# jqGrid SetCell and SaveCell blanking out the cell after closing a modal dialog

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I have a cell-editable jqgrid with a column that has an edittype of 'button'.  When the cell is clicked, the button appears.  when the button is clicked, a modal dialog appears allowing the user to select a value from a grid.  This is all working fine.

When the user clicks the 'OK' button on the modal dialog after picking a value from the grid, I'd like to set the cell value with the value selected by the user and save the cell.

Instead of setting and saving the cell value, the cell is blanked out.  Not sure why.

Here is the relevant jqGrid / modal dialog code:

```
// global variables
base.selectedCode = null;
base.liaGridSelectedId = null;
base.liaGridSelectedICol = null;
base.liaGridSelectedIRow = null;

    $("#liaGrid").jqGrid({
        datatype: "local",
        data: base.liaGridData,
        cellEdit: true,
        cellsubmit: 'clientArray',
        height: 140,
        colNames: ['ID', 'Class Code', 'State', 'Location Type'],
        colModel: [
                    { name: 'id', index: 'id', width: 90, sorttype: "int", editable: false, hidden: true },
                    { name: 'ClassCode', index: 'ClassCode', width: 90, sortable: false, editable: true, edittype: "button",
                        editoptions: {
                            dataEvents: [{
                                type: 'click',
                                fn: function (e) {
                                    e.preventDefault();
                                    var rowid = $('#liaGrid').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
                                    base.liaGridSelectedId = parseInt(rowid);
                                    $('#class-dialog').dialog('option', { width: 100, height: 200, position: 'center', title: 'Pick a Class' });
                                    $('#class-dialog').dialog('open');

                                    return true;
                                }
                            }]
                        }
                    },
                    { name: 'LocationType', index: 'LocationType', width: 90, sortable: false, editable: true, edittype: "select", editoptions: { value: "0:;1:Rural;2:Suburban;3:Urban"} }
                ],
        caption: "Liability Model",
        beforeEditCell: function (rowid, cellname, value, iRow, iCol) {
            base.liaGridSelectedICol = iCol;
            base.liaGridSelectedIRow = iRow;
        }
    });


    var infoDialog = $('#class-dialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        show: 'fade',
        hide: 'fade',
        resizable: true,
        buttons: {
            "Ok": function () {
                if (base.selectedCode != null) {

                    $("#liaGrid").jqGrid('setCell', base.liaGridSelectedId, 'ClassCode', base.selectedCode);

                    $("#liaGrid").jqGrid('saveCell', base.liaGridSelectedIRow, base.liaGridSelectedICol);

                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            },
            "Cancel": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }

    });
```

As seen above, I'm attempting to use jqGrid('setCell') and jqGrid('saveCell') to update and save the contents of the cell.  Not sure why this fails to succeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this to work in case anyone encounters a similar issue.  I had to add the [afterSaveCell](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acell_editing) handler to the grid:

```
afterSaveCell: function (rowid, name, val, iRow, iCol) {
    if (base.liaGridSelectedICol == 1) {
        $("#liaGrid").jqGrid('setRowData', rowid, { ClassCode: base.selectedCode });
    }
}
```

FYI - base.selectedCode is set in the modal.

Odd thing, this only worked after calling the setCell and saveCell methods.  Without these unsuccessful calls to set and save at the cell level, the above handler was not called.

If someone has a more appropriate approach to solving this problem I'd like to hear it.

Thanks